# Appending HTML string to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

How to append a HTML string such as

```
var str = '<p>Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';
```

to the `<div>` with the id `test`?

(Btw `div.innerHTML += str;` is not acceptable.)

Answer (score 403, accepted):

Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) which [is supported in all current browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#browser_compatibility):

```
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
```

The position parameter `beforeend` will add inside the element, after its last child.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/euQ5n/

Comment: @alex It's the same concept: parsing a HTML string and putting it into the DOM. But the functionality is different - `innerHTML` puts the string into the element (replacing all children), whereas `insertAdjacentHTML` puts it (1) before the element, (2) after the element, (3) inside the element before the first child, or (4) inside the element after the last child.

Comment: @alex `insertAdjacentHTML` is faster than appending to `innerHTML`, because `insertAdjacentHTML` doesn't serialize and reparse the existing children of the element.

Comment: Also, `insertAdjacentHTML` maintains the values of altered form elements, whereas appending to `innerHTML` rebuilds the element and loses all form context.

Comment: Cool but I'd suggest 'beforebegin' instead of 'beforeend'

Comment: not to be confused with `insertAdjacent`**`Element`**`(..)`, which requires an actual `Element` as its second parameter, not a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement

Comment: Thanks, I've been stuck on this for 2 hours after trying to rip out jquery append() I thought div.innerHTML += str would be equivalent but then some of my dynamic components broke. Thanks @alex for the explanation.

Answer (score 50):

### Performance

`AppendChild` (E) is more than 2x faster than other solutions on chrome and safari, `insertAdjacentHTML`(F) is fastest on firefox. The `innerHTML=` (B) (do not confuse with `+=` (A)) is second fast solution on all browsers and it is much more handy than E and F.

### Details

Set up environment (2019.07.10) MacOs High Sierra 10.13.4 on Chrome 75.0.3770 (64-bit), Safari 11.1.0 (13604.5.6), Firefox 67.0.0 (64-bit)

[image]

- on Chrome E (140k operations per second) is fastest, B (47k) and F (46k) are second, A (332) is slowest
- on firefox F (94k) is fastest, then B(80k), D (73k), E(64k), C (21k)  slowest is A(466)
- on Safari E(207k) is fastest, then B(89k), F(88k), D(83k), C (25k), slowest is A(509)

You can replay test in your machine [here](https://jsperf.com/insert-html-test)

```js
function A() {    
  container.innerHTML += '<p>A: Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';
}

function B() {    
  container.innerHTML = '<p>B: Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';
}

function C() {    
  $('#container').append('<p>C: Just some <span>text</span> here</p>');
}

function D() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = 'D: Just some <span>text</span> here';
  container.appendChild(p);
}

function E() {    
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var s = document.createElement("span"); 
  s.appendChild( document.createTextNode("text ") );
  p.appendChild( document.createTextNode("E: Just some ") );
  p.appendChild( s );
  p.appendChild( document.createTextNode(" here") );
  container.appendChild(p);
}

function F() {    
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>F: Just some <span>text</span> here</p>');
}

A();
B();
C();
D();
E();
F();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

This snippet only for show code used in test (in jsperf.com) - it not perform test itself. 
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Readability is usually more important than performance. But thanks for the leg work.

Comment: @Jay optimisation should be used only when it is needed and often must be rich commented

Comment: using innerHTML seems not good since the browser has to parse the whole bunch of HTML again instead of adding to the tail

Answer (score 35):

Is this acceptable?

```
var child = document.createElement('div');
child.innerHTML = str;
child = child.firstChild;
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(child);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rD6BZ/).

**But**, [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7327125/31671) is a better solution.

Comment: @Šime Working with the DOM API *always* feels like a hack :P Would you prefer to unserialise the string *without* `innerHTML`?

Comment: Well yes, if there is another way to utilize the browser's HTML parser, I would love to know...

Comment: @Šime - I think there's only two ways to utilize the browser's HTML parser, innerHTML and document.write. And if you think innerHTML is a hack ...

Comment: @Alohci There *is* another way: `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Comment: @Šime - So I see. I must admit I didn't know about that. I've up voted Neil's answer. I'm trying to find the spec for it. The link from developer.mozilla.org doesn't lead to it any more.

Comment: @Alohci It's in the HTML5 standard under ["3.5 Dynamic markup insertion"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#dom-insertadjacenthtml). Interestingly, for some reason it has been ditched from the HTML Living Standard (which is a more relevant document when it comes to HTML).

Comment: @Šime -Thanks. I found the WHATWG version. It's in the [DOM Parsing and Serialization](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html#insertadjacenthtml()) spec. It indicates that as well as innerHTML and insertAdjacentHTML, there's outerHTML and, I think, createContextualFragment.

Comment: @Alohci A new spec? Neat `^_^`

Comment: @Alohci, @Šime: `createContextualFragment()` is a method of DOM Range and does use the browser's HTML parser.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesCalo: Yeah, but the example the OP gave did.

Answer (score 11):

The idea is to use `innerHTML` on an intermediary element and then move all of its child nodes to where you really want them via `appendChild`.

```
var target = document.getElementById('test');
var str = '<p>Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';

var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = str;
while (temp.firstChild) {
  target.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
}
```

This avoids wiping out any event handlers on `div#test` but still allows you to append a string of HTML.

Answer (score 4):

The right way is using `insertAdjacentHTML`. In Firefox earlier than 8, you can fall back to using `Range.createContextualFragment` if your `str` contains no `script` tags.

If your `str` contains `script` tags, you need to remove `script` elements from the fragment returned by `createContextualFragment` before inserting the fragment. Otherwise, the scripts will run. (`insertAdjacentHTML` marks scripts unexecutable.)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `createContextualFragment `. I was searching for a way to make some html includes with scripts run only if the user agrees to set a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Quick **Hack**:

---

```
<script>
document.children[0].innerHTML="<h1>QUICK_HACK</h1>";
</script>
```

---

**Use Cases**:

1: Save as .html file and run in chrome or firefox or edge. (IE wont work)

2: Use in http://js.do

**In Action:**
http://js.do/HeavyMetalCookies/quick_hack

**Broken down with comments:**

```
<script>

//: The message "QUICK_HACK" 
//: wrapped in a header #1 tag.
var text = "<h1>QUICK_HACK</h1>";

//: It's a quick hack, so I don't
//: care where it goes on the document,
//: just as long as I can see it.
//: Since I am doing this quick hack in
//: an empty file or scratchpad, 
//: it should be visible.
var child = document.children[0];

//: Set the html content of your child
//: to the message you want to see on screen.
child.innerHTML = text;

</script>
```

**Reason Why I posted:**

JS.do has two must haves:

1. No autocomplete
2. Vertical monitor friendly

But doesn't show console.log messages.
Came here looking for a quick solution.
I just want to see the results of
a few lines of scratchpad code, the
other solutions are too much work.

Answer (score 1):

This can solve

```
 document.getElementById("list-input-email").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class=""><input type="text" name="" value="" class="" /></div>');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please explain your code as part of an answer  to provide some context rather than just pasting a long single line of code. Although you understand it others may not understand what its doing.

Answer (score 1):

InnerHTML clear all data like event for existing nodes

append child with firstChild adds only first child to innerHTML. For example if we have to append:

```
 <p>text1</p><p>text2</p>
```

only text1 will show up

What about this:

adds special tag to innerHTML by append child and then edit outerHTML by deleting tag we've created. Don't know how smart it is but it works for me
or you might change outerHTML to innerHTML so it doesn't have to use function replace

```js
function append(element, str)
{

  var child = document.createElement('someshittyuniquetag');
  
  child.innerHTML = str;

  element.appendChild(child);

  child.outerHTML = child.outerHTML.replace(/<\/?someshittyuniquetag>/, '');

// or Even child.outerHTML = child.innerHTML


  
}
```

```html
<div id="testit">
This text is inside the div
<button onclick="append(document.getElementById('testit'), '<button>dadasasdas</button>')">To div</button>
<button onclick="append(this, 'some text')">to this</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is that not acceptable?

`document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += str`

would be the textbook way of doing it.

Comment: It would [kill event handlers](http://jsfiddle.net/v6qbc/) attached to `#test` though. That is generally not desirable.

Comment: Interesting that it does that.  Doesn't seem logical really.

Comment: It's logical I guess if you think about the serialising of the HTML to a string and then setting the HTML back.

Comment: I guess the JavaScript would have to be run again to reset the event handler.  Fair enough.

Comment: @Nick You don't want to stringify (serialize) a part of the DOM just so that you can concatenate it with another string and then parse the whole thing back into the DOM. As alex said, the serialization won't record bound event handlers (among other things). Even if he serialization could capture everything, you still wouldn't want to do it.

Answer (score -1):

**Shortest** - 18 chars (not confuse `+=` (mention by OP) with `=` more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140673/860099))

```
test.innerHTML=str
```

```js
var str = '<p>Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';

test.innerHTML=str
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: The question was about _appending_, not _replacing_.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to my Question was just this; a simple Map with an empty value; and all I can get is a very heavy answer and not precise. I wonder who closed my question... didn't even bother to read

```
"use strict"
try{
  const fruits = new Map([["Banana",""],["Apples", ""], ["Orange"," "]]);

let text = "<h1>Fruits</h1>" + "<ul>";

fruits.forEach(function(value, key){
  text += "<li>" + key + value + "<br>" + "</li>" });

text +="</li> ";

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text;
}
catch(err){
 document.getElementById('theError').innerHTML = err;
}
```