# convert innerHTML string to DOM structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to convert the following string to DOM structure.

```
text node <div>div node</div>text node<p>paraph node</p> text node
```

One approach is,

```
mydiv = document.createElement('div');
mydiv.innerHTML = 'text node <div>div node</div>text node<p>paraph node</p> text node';
```

In this approach, the DOM structure is wrapped by another div, which is not i wanted.

After do searching and reading, I found `document.createDocumentFragment()` is the best way, because when append a `fragment` to node, it just append `fragment's childNodes`, not `fragment itself`

unfortunately, `innerHTML` method is not available in a `fragment`.

what should i do? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
mydiv.innerHTML = 'text node <div>div node</div>text node<p>paraph node</p> text node';


while( mydiv.firstChild ) {
    frag.appendChild( mydiv.firstChild );
}

document.body.appendChild( frag );
```

Comment: Good one, check firstElementChild also.

Comment: This cuts the node from its origin, what about if i want to copy instead?

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the solutions on this page and none were working sufficiently for my case (a more complex HTML string). I ended using this very simple approach with *insertAdjacentHTML* that I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7327125/388412

```
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
```

Answer (score 1):

Esailija's answer will work cross-browser and in most situations and is what I'd favour in general, for now. Another option designed for precisely this task is the [`createContextualFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.createContextualFragment) method of `Range` (see also [DOM Parsing and Serialization spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html#dom-range-createcontextualfragment)). The idea is that it will create a `DocumentFragment` for the specified HTML string that is relevant to the location in the document represented by the start of a Range. Unfortunately, this method is not supported in IE <= 9, although [IE 10 will support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#createContextualFragment).

Here's an example. Let's assume you're planning to insert the fragment at the end of the body:

```
var html = "text node <div>div node</div>text node<p>paraph node</p> text node";
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(document.body);
range.collapse(false);
var frag = range.createContextualFragment(html);

document.body.appendChild( frag );
```

Comment: `createContextualFragment` is the best way to convert string to DOM nodes. `mydiv.firstChild` is tricky, you have to loop all the nodes in `mydiv` which lose performance.Thanks for your great answer

Comment: @wukong no, you will only have to loop the immediate children of mydiv, not all nodes. And the performance difference is equal or negligible at best, completely irrelevant at worst because drawing the graphics on the screen is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i just combine Tim's answer and Esailija's answer to one single function for convennience.

```
   function createDocumentFragment (inMarkup) {

        var range, fragment, dummy, elem;

        if (document.createRange && (range = document.createRange())
                && range.selectNodeContents
                && range.createContextualFragment) {

            range.collapse(false);

            range.selectNodeContents(document.body);

            fragment = range.createContextualFragment(inMarkup);

        } else {

            dummy = document.createElement('div');

            fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

            dummy.innerHTML = inMarkup;

            while((elem = dummy.firstChild)) {

                fragment.appendChild(elem);

            }

        }

        return fragment;

    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend just using a battle tested library such as jQuery for this.

Comment: @Esailija: I wouldn't. jQuery does nothing with `createContextualFragment()` and your answer does the job fine.

Comment: @TimDown Not sure what you mean with "jQuery does nothing with createContextualFragment()" as jQuery doesn't use it all. By battle tested I meant that this code(and mine) will have tons of bugs that jQuery's buildFragment doesn't.

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, that was what I meant about `createContextualFragment()`. Re. jQuery's `buildFragment()`, you may be right. I haven't looked into it deeply and there seems to be no documentation on it whatsoever on the jQuery site.

Comment: @TimDown It's not documented because its meant for internal use only. There is no need for explicit use of fragments anyway if you are using jQuery/remotely decent dom library. But if you read the source for `$.buildFragment` and `$.clean`, you can easily see that we are reinventing square wheels here.