# Handlebars/templating use template as an object

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

I am looking at using Handlbars templating for my project.
Can handlebars return a DOM object or can it only return HTML.
For instance if I want to append a child to a DIV can I call DIV.appendChild(myTemplate);
Something like this:

```
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
for(var i = 0;i<myData.length;i++){
    var source   = $("#my-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var values = myData[i];
    parentDiv.appendChild(template(values));
}
```

From this I get an arg 1 of appendChild is not an object error thrown, because the rendered template is html/string.

**Is there something I can call in handlebars to gerenate objects?**

**Am I trying to stetch templating too far or is there another solution that behaves in this manner or am I stuck writing createElement manually?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327056/appending-html-string-to-the-dom)

Use the element.insertAdjecentHTML method to append html string and the dom should convert it into a set of nodes.
So you can write something like this :

```
parentDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template(values));
```

Comment: thats a good link, thanks, some interesting techniques on there.