# Append html(text) to element without affecting siblings?

Tags: javascript, dom

I always use `appendChild` to add something to other element, because if I use:

```
innerHTML +=  'added stringgggggggggg';
```

then this messes up the dynamic element,for example `<form>`, with filled values (it resets field values to empty).

Is there any shorter way to add smth to element, without `appenChild` and without using JQuery?

Comment: You don’t need an element to add text; just use a text node. I’m not aware of a way without using `appendChild` (or `insertAdjacentHTML`, etc.), though.

Comment: Simply create a helper function and reuse it, something like `appendText(element, 'added stringgggggggggg')`

Comment: Does this help : - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33312039/2968762

Comment: `appendChild` is actually the *shortest* way in pure JS

Comment: @rvighne Not when you have to use `document.createTextNode`  for creating  a textNode before using the `appendChild`.

Comment: @Vohuman there are very few cases you need to be appending raw textNodes (Usually only when you need inline spans). Any other time it's best to concatenate an entire string first, then assign it to a block element last.

Comment: @Vohuman Also, you can use the [`new Text()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/Text) instead of `document.createTextNode()` to save some typing.

Comment: Why do you need it to be shorter? Is it too much to type? If so, configure a template in your IDE/editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to evaluate and append a raw HTML string to an element.

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>put me inside at the end</p>');
```

By changing the `position` attribute you can insert before the element, after it, inside it at the beginning, or inside it at the end.

```
<!-- beforebegin -->
<p>
  <!-- afterbegin -->
  foo
  <!-- beforeend -->
</p>
<!-- afterend -->
```

Unlike `innerHTML`, `insertAdjacentHTML()` won't cause the browser won't to re-evaluate the entire DOM node you're injecting into, so form field values will be maintained.

```js
var parentEl = document.getElementById('parent');
parentEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>this paragraph was inserted at the end of the form without affecting the form field values!<p>');
```

```html
<form id="parent">
  <input type="text" value="insert something after form"><br>
  <input type="text" value="without affecting the values"><br>
  <input type="text" value="in the form fields"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: @Vohuman and the answer is no. That was the first line I wrote.

Comment: @Vohuman the OP didn't ask about writing shortcut functions or show and sample code for a shortcut function they were trying to write.

Comment: I was providing background and context for browser behaviour which lends context to *all* the insert and append methods. The OP's example may show them adding a "string", which I assume was for brevity, because right before that they say "add something to other element".

Comment: I've updated my answer with the `insertAdjacentHTML` method since that seems to satisfy the OP's original requirements.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I was about to close the question as a duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327056/appending-html-string-to-the-dom). I'll remove my comments.

Comment: @Vohuman thanks for being persistent. I've also added a runnable code snippet to demonstrate.