# Not able to get the end result with for/while LOOP Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to append some html to and element;
What i want to do is to count the elements inside a div, then if that number matches certain condition then append some html.

```
//count how much divs with the class .col-lg are inside #looped
var counting = $("#looped  .col-lg").length;
console.log(counting);

//If statement that works;
if (counting == 12 ) {
  insideLoop.append('<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg servicios d-flex flex-column mt-sm-3 justify-content-center align-items-center"></div><div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg servicios d-flex flex-column mt-sm-3 justify-content-center align-items-center"></div>');
}

//But i wanted to start from number 3 - 6 - 9 - 12 etc...
```

I thought maybe with a for loop a would get it , but i always end up on a dead end or an endless loop.

Comment: You may want to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327056/appending-html-string-to-the-dom/7327125

Comment: What is `insideLoop`?

Comment: are you trying to render this div every 3 iterations? is that the problem?

Comment: @Mohammad insideLoop is a variable that i forgot to add;
var insideLoop = $('#looped');

Comment: @Roysh Yes!! So at first it looks if there are 3 divs l IF yes then DO; else look for 6 divs , look for 9 divs etc..

Comment: so why not instead of `(counting == 12 )` use `(counting % 3 === 0 )` ?

Comment: Do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/5zea4osq/

Comment: @Mohammad I took Roysh advice and made it work like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/xbo6yu70/4/

Comment: @Roysh Thanks! It did work :D

Comment: @Simo I'd appreciate if you'll accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer - You should use the **mod operator** for every three iterations

```
var counting = $("#looped  .col-lg").length;



if (counting % 3 === 0) {
  insideLoop.append('<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg servicios d-flex flex-column mt-sm-3 justify-content-center align-items-center"></div><div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg servicios d-flex flex-column mt-sm-3 justify-content-center align-items-center"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Roysh's Comment Did work for me ,

I replaced (counting == 12) with (counting % 3 === 0 ) .