# How receive name and value attribute of button in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, request

I try to receive a name and value from button in Flask by `request.form` after clicked a Save or Search button. I get tuple from select and option but not for button. I wonder what I am doing wrong?

**signup.html:**

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Choose</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="select">
      <option value="o1">o1</option>
      <option value="o2">o2</option>
      <option value="o3">o3</option>
    </select>
    <label type="button" id="search" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Search</label>
    <label type="button" id="save" name="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Save</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Python code:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import json
from my_func import my_func

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def signUpUser():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form)
        select = request.form['select']  
        dict_to_json = {'status': 'OK', 'select': select}
        if select == "my_func":
            result = my_func('my_input')
            dict_to_json['my_func'] = result
        return json.dumps(dict_to_json)
     return render_template('signup.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
    app.run()
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#search').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('success')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And from this I receive:
    `ImmutableMultiDict([('select', 'o1')])`
but I expected:
    `ImmutableMultiDict([('select', 'o1'),('search','Search')])`

Comment: If flask is your framework, then use flask request method. There are lots of example in internet on how flask beautifully incorporate HTML form and get form input field into flask file which you can use python language to use it as variable to your coding there. The same principle applied to your question, but rather form's input, you are asking form's button (which labelled 'search' and the other 'save'. This time you just name your button element (in HTML) with name = 'search' and the other button element with name = 'save', then use flask request.get('search) and flask request.get('save')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post method will send you only the input fields (`input`, `textarea`, `select`, radio-buttons, etc).

So, to do what you want, you would have to transform the `label` element, into an `input` element, and make it behave like a submit button.

You can do so by doing:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Choose</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="select">
      <option value="o1">o1</option>
      <option value="o2">o2</option>
      <option value="o3">o3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="search" name="action" value="Search" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
    <input type="submit" id="save" name="action" value="Save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Since you have the same name, you can access the info as `response.form['action']` that will be or `"Search"` or  `"Save"`.

Solving as you said:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Choose</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="select">
      <option value="o1">o1</option>
      <option value="o2">o2</option>
      <option value="o3">o3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="search" name="action" value="Search" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
    <input type="button" id="save" name="action" value="Save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('[name="action"]').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                $("where you want to insert").html(response)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It work. But I still wonder, how to do that with `type="button"`. I wanna put response in the same page.

Comment: Can you detail more what you mean by "put response in the same page"?

Comment: After click "Search" all content lost and only result appear. Instead of this I wanna after click "Search" have the same content like first page and put result of search in the div.

Comment: In this case, I think you'll need JavaScript. To the `type=button` element, you'll have to bind a javascript function that will be executed every time it is clicked. This JavaScript will to the request and will receive the HTML, then, you'll inject this HTML into the document in the section you want. Maybe Flask provides an easier way to do so. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: To see how to make the request from JavaScript, you can take a look at this link: https://www.ajax-tutor.com/ . To see how to add HTML string into the document, you can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327056/appending-html-string-to-the-dom/7327125

Comment: Sorry, I completed misread the question and provided you with a answer that didn't solve what you asked. I'm editing my answer to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use built in flask request method, something like this ...

In python flask:
... request.form.get('search') ..

which corresponding to your HTML with element in the form with name = 'search'

The same thing with 'save'

In python flask:
... request.form.get('save') ..

which corresponding to your HTML form with element name = 'save'

Just ensure in your HTML form the name ="something" is unique in that form.