# Replace whole div content with new content in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am acquiring the html in an html page. However I want to replace the entire contents of

```
<div id="fontsListing"></div>
```

with new contents.

I'm using the following but the regex here is messing up with my closing div tags.
How can I simply empty the contents of the `fontsListing` div
and enter in `req.body.savedHtml`?
Please note I can't use innerHtml as I need the actual javascript values to send to an api.

```
var newHtml = data.replace(/<div id="fontsListing">[\s\S]*?<\/div>/, "<div id=\"fontsListing\">" + req.body.savedHtml + "</div>");
```

Comment: Can you clarify why using innerhtml wouldnt work. To me it looks like youre trying to reimplement that method.

Comment: Honestly you can't do this reliably with regex, as the end tag (</div>) could be part of an inner DIV. You need to parse the html and change in it there, then serialize back

Comment: @Achtung Because if I used innerhtml it would just alter the content in the dom of the html file. I need the actual html to save to an api, to then actually physically save the file.

Comment: Better to use a dom parser than regex

Answer (score -1):

Found out the answer, `(.*)` is your friend, please see below:

```
var newHtml = data.replace(/<div id="fontsListing">(.*)<\/div>/g, "<div id=\"fontsListing\">" + req.body.savedHtml + "</div>");
```

Comment: Hey mate ! Is your question related to this one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327056/appending-html-string-to-the-dom   After I answered I became curious about what you are looking for? May be I have less information about it ?