# Click eventlistener not working for dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, createelement

click eventlistener for archiveBtn is not responding when its clicked.what's wrong.`

```
function readMail(id,mailbox){
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#read-view').style.display = 'block';
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    document.querySelector('#read-view').innerHTML = `
    <b>From: </b>${email.sender}<br>
    <b>To: </b>${email.recipients}<br>
    <b>Subject: </b>${email.subject}<br>
    <b>Timestamp: </b>${email.timestamp}<br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="reply">Reply</button> `
    // archive
    if (mailbox != 'sent'){
      const archiveBtn= document.createElement('button');
      archiveBtn.className = email.archived? 'btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger' : 'btn btn-sm btn-outline-success';
      archiveBtn.innerHTML = email.archived? 'Unarchive' : 'Archive';
      document.querySelector('#read-view').append(archiveBtn);
      archiveBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log('This element has been clicked!');
        fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: !email.archived
          })
        })
        .then(()=>loadMailbox('inbox'));
      });
    }
```

`

i tried onClick,tried writing outside if statement,none of it works.
note:the readMail function is called by eventlistener in other function.

Comment: So is there more code after this that alters the innerHTML? because that code is working for me when I mock it up. My guess is you are doing  `innerHTML += ''` somewhere after it.

Comment: yes i am adding this,    document.querySelector('#read-view').innerHTML+=`<hr>${email.body}`;i want it after the button.

Comment: is there any method better than creating div with createelement and adding above innerhtml?

Comment: using innerHTML is like using a whiteboard. When you use it, you erase everything and you rewrite it all. All those events you added are gone. Just append the string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327056/appending-html-string-to-the-dom